# Regex one-liner for matching only what comes after a certain word?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to extract song names from a list like this:  `'some text here, songs: song1, song2, song3, fro: othenkl'` and get `['song1', 'song2', 'song3']`. So I try to do it in one regex:

```
result =  re.findall('[Ss]ongs?:?.*', 'songs: songname1, songname2,')
print re.findall('(?:(\w+),)*', result[0])
```

This matches perfectly:  `['', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'songname1', '', 'songname2', '']` (except for the empty strings, but nbd.

But I want to do it in one line, so I do the following:

```
print re.findall('[Ss]ongs?:?(?:(\w+),)*','songs: songname1, songname2,')
```

But I do not understand why this is unable to capture the same as the two regexes above:

```
['', 'name1', 'name2']
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in one line?  It would be useful to be concise here.  thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `re.findall` in this case, you better to use `re.search` to find the sequence of songs then split the result with comma `,`. Also you don't need to use character class `[Ss]` to match the Capitals you can use Ignore case flag (`re.I`) :

```
>>> s ='some text here, songs: song1, song2, song3, fro: othenkl'
>>> re.search(r'(?<=songs:)(.+),', s,flags=re.I).group(1).split(',')
[' song1', ' song2', ' song3']
```

`(?<=songs:)` is a positive look behind which will makes your regex engine match the strings precede by `songs:` and `(.+),` will match the largest string after `songs:` which follows by comma that is the sequence of your songs.

Also as a more general way instead of specifying comma at the end of your regex you can capture the song names based on this fact that they are followed by this patter `\s\w+:`.

```
>>> re.search(r'(?<=songs:)(.+)(?=\s\w+:)', s).group(1).split(',')
[' song1', ' song2', ' song3', '']
```

Comment: So, I guess you are still kinda doing it in two steps, even though it is a one-liner.  Because, you still have to split the result from the `search` by `split(',')`.

Comment: Note that this will fail if the capture group does not find any match: `re.search(...)` will return `None`, for which the above expressions make no sense anymore.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't do it in one pattern with the re module.
What you can do is to use the [regex module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) instead with this pattern:

```
regex.findall(r'(?:\G(?!\A), |\msongs: )(\w++)(?!:)', s)
```

Where `\G` is the position after the previous match, `\A` the start of the string, `\m` a word boundary followed by word characters, and `++` a possessive quantifier.